# jQuery create new array from array + var and use new array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array and a variable i am trying to build a new array from and then use that new array.

My existing array and var look like this

```
var RColor = '#007cc4';   
var stateHTML = {
    "US-VA": {"location": "Virginia"},
    "US-PA": {"location": "Pennsylvania"},
    "US-TN": {"location": "Tennessee"},
    "US-WV": {"location": "West Virginia"},
    "US-NV": {"location": "Nevada"},
    //"US-TX": {"location": "Texas"},
    "US-NH": {"location": "New Hampshire"},
    "US-NY": {"location": "New York"},
    "US-HI": {"location": "Hawaii"},
    "US-VT": {"location": "Vermont"},
    "US-NM": {"location": "New Mexico"},
    "US-ME": {"location": "Maine"},
    "US-OH": {"location": "Ohio"},
    "US-OK": {"location": "Oklahoma"},
    "US-ID": {"location": "Idaho"},     
};
```

My code i am trying to use to make the new array is like this

```
var activeColors = [];
$.each(stateHTML, function(index, value){
    activeColors.push(index + ':' + RColor +',');
});
```

Then i am trying to reuse the new array here

```
series: {
     regions: [{values: {
                    return:activeColors
                    },
                    attribute: 'fill'
                    }]
   },
```

If i hard code the regions values like so it works

```
series: {
     regions: [{values: {
                    "US-VA": RColor,
                    "US-PA": RColor,
                    "US-TN": RColor,
                    "US-WV": RColor,
                    "US-NV": RColor,
                    },
                    attribute: 'fill'
                    }]
   },
```

How can i make the new array based on my stateHTML and RColor and then use that new array like the above that works?

You can see the full example code here

http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/ymgkkuzL/223/

When working it will color only the the states specified in the new activeColors array specified in the series:region values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `activeColors` to be an array, nor do you want to push *strings* into it.  You want it to be an ***object*** and you want to set each key/value pair in the loop.

```
var activeColors = {};
$.each(stateHTML, function(index, value){
    activeColors[index] = RColor;
});
```

Then you can use this in place of the hard-coded object.

```
series: {
    regions: [{
        values: activeColors,
        attribute: 'fill'
    }]
}
```

Comment: OMG you are awesome!!!! This works!!! http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/ymgkkuzL/224/

Comment: @Aaron: That sounds like a completely different question.

Comment: your right...i will post...just thought i would ask :)

Comment: Posted and wanted to thanks again for this help!!! really awesome and can't thank you enough...been messing with this all morning.